# Is the rate of light emissions actually the frequency of the light?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, relativity, frequency, doppler-effect

I am confusing with the concept of frequency in the context of Doppler effect studying SR. The Schutz says, if the source emits pulses more frequently, then the observer would see the lights not only more frequently, but also with more energy!

Is that true? Can't we emit the LOW frequency(energy) light like infrared pulses at HIGH frequency(rate) about 10^100 Hz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question raises several concerns. From a purely signal processing point-of-view, where the aforementioned pulse is not a photon, but rather a time-domain pulse of a certain duration (here less than 10^-100 seconds)--then NO: you cannot have pulses shorter than the period of wave in question--as the wave an be defined. Consider sound: when a 440Hz A note gets short enough, you just hear a "click"--not a well defined pitch.

The other concern is with the Lorentz invariance of de Broglie relation: when you boost an EM wave, the frequency and energy-density change--they are reference frame dependent--but the number of photons simply cannot change--as it's quantized. If it did change, there would be "special" velocities where you add or subtract a photon--and that's just nonsense. Others have worked it out here:
http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/uoveromega.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The rate emission of photons is a measure of total power: 100 photons per second vs 1,000,000,000 photons per second. The individual photon emitters are, for example, electrons being driven back and forth in a radio circuit: the photons are quanta of radio waves, with the frequency of the oscillator circuit setting the energy of each photon by Planck's relation, $ E=hf $, and the number of photons per second, the power, controlled by the curret in the antenna.

So they are two different things: photon frequency is controlled by the emission process, and total power is how many emitters you can activate per second.